# "Duplicate initialization of WorkManager" error occurred during Spring Boot JMS Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c, spring-jms

Getting the below error when i start the spring boot application. Actually i am trying to read message from Weblogic 12c JMS Queue using @JmsListener. As i am using weblogic queue, i have added the wlclient.jar in the referenced library.

I referred to this link[Spring JMS Integration](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-jms) to develop Weblogic JMS Asynchronous integration using @JmsListener, But what i have done extra is created connection factory bean for Weblogic as i want to integrate with Weblogic.

**Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: error initializing kernel caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Duplicate initialization of WorkManager**

As per the above message, I need to stop the duplicate work manager. Is it possible to stop the duplicate workmanager?

**Configuration:**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

/**
 * 
 * @author karthikeyan
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class JMSConfig {

    @Bean
    public InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:9400/");
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        return (ConnectionFactory) getInitialContext().lookup("jms/MyJMSConnectionFactory");
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory() throws NamingException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = containerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(1);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-5");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }   


}
```

**JMS Receiver**

```
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * 
 * @author karthikeyan
 *
 */
@Component
public class JMSReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "jms/MyJMSQueue")
    public void receiveMessage(Shipment msg) {
        System.out.println("Received Sterling XML: " + msg);
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
2021-09-14 11:26:46.794  WARN 6296 --- [ntContainer#0-1] j.e.r.corba._DEFAULT_.rpc.encoding       : "IOP00810210: (MARSHAL) Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream"

org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: 
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadError(ORBUtilSystemException.java:6976) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:991) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:822) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:681) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:431) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:120) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1961) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher._DispatcherImpl_Stub.dispatchSyncTranFuture(Unknown Source) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:334) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:381) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:59) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createDestination(JMSSession.java:3192) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createQueue(JMSSession.java:2577) [classes/:na]
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.createQueue(WLSessionImpl.java:938) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:85) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:59) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:115) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:222) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1264) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1236) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) [spring-jms-5.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: error initializing kernel caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Duplicate initialization of WorkManager
    at weblogic.work.WorkManagerFactory.set(WorkManagerFactory.java:107)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteQueueFactory.initialize(ExecuteQueueFactory.java:25)
    at weblogic.kernel.Kernel.initialize(Kernel.java:103)
    at weblogic.kernel.Kernel.ensureInitialized(Kernel.java:64)
    at weblogic.kernel.Kernel.getConfig(Kernel.java:121)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSRMIEnvironment.isRefreshClientRuntimeDescriptor(WLSRMIEnvironment.java:95)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.<clinit>(StubInfo.java:50)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:611)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1861)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:506)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:681)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.readExternal(WLContextImpl.java:520)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.readExternal(WLEventContextImpl.java:413)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1039)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:822)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:681)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:431)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:120)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1961)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:603)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:199)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:915)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher._DispatcherImpl_Stub.dispatchSyncTranFuture(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:334)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:381)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:59)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createDestination(JMSSession.java:3192)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createQueue(JMSSession.java:2577)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.createQueue(WLSessionImpl.java:938)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:222)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at weblogic.kernel.Kernel.ensureInitialized(Kernel.java:66) ~[classes/:12.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.kernel.Kernel.getConfig(Kernel.java:121) ~[classes/:12.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSRMIEnvironment.isRefreshClientRuntimeDescriptor(WLSRMIEnvironment.java:95) ~[classes/:na]
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.<clinit>(StubInfo.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1861) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:506) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:681) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.readExternal(WLContextImpl.java:520) ~[classes/:na]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.readExternal(WLEventContextImpl.java:413) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1039) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:977) [na:1.8.0_221]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace instead of a snippet, include the configuration and code you are using. Currently there is too little information to answer this.

Comment: Why did you remove the actual question and just dumped a stacktace?! And please use some formatting for links, code etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum , Sorry for the formatting issue, please check now and let me know if you still see something missing.

Comment: Is there a reason you configure all the beans yourself? Looks like you want to do a JNDI lookup but instead the queue is being created. I would suggest removing the `myFactory` and `containerFactory` beans and let Spring Boot configure those (which will also setup JNDI). You could also specify `spring.jms.jndi-name=jms/MyJMSConnectionFactory` and use auto-configuration all throughout your app.